# deleting loan row in database after returning book

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a loan system for books and I have a profile page that displays the loans you have taken out, underneath each one is a button that takes you to a form where you fill out the condition of the book, under that is another button that will send the data to a returns table in my database, I want to delete the loan in the loan table because if not then the loan keeps displaying in the profile page and the user can return the same book as many times as they want. any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks.

profile.blade.php

```
<?php
use App\Requests;
use App\Loan;
$request = Requests::where('userid', auth()->user()->userid)->get();
?>

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h1>Profile: {{ Auth::user()->f_name }}</h1></div>

            <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="container">

            <h3>Requests</h3>

               @foreach ($request as $request)
                <ul>

                    <h4>Title: {{$request->r_title}}</h4>
                    <h4>Author: {{$request->r_author}}</h4>
                    <h4>Year: {{$request->r_year}}</h4>
                    <h4>Condition: {{$request->r_condition}}</h4>
                    <br/>
                </ul>

                @endforeach
                </div>
                <div class="container">

                <h3>Loans</h3>

                @foreach ($loan as $loan)
                <ul>

                    <h4>Title: {{$loan->title}}</h4>
                    <h4>Start Date: {{$loan->startdate}}</h4>
                    <h4>Due Date: {{$loan->duedate}}</h4>
                    <br/>

                    <form action="{{url('returnform/'.$loan->loanid)}}" method="GET">
                        <input type="submit" name="returnbtn" value="returnform">
                    </form>

                </ul>
                @endforeach

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
@endsection
```

returnform.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h1>Return Book</h1></div>

            <div class="panel-body">

                        <form action="{{url('returns')}}" method="POST">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}    
                        <div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="lid" value="{{$loan->loanid}}" id="lid">
                            <input type="hidden" name="re_bookid" value="{{$loan->bookid}}" id="re_bookid">
                            <input type="hidden" name="re_title" value="{{$loan->title}}" id="re_title">  
                            <input type="hidden" name="re_ddate" value="{{$loan->duedate}}" id="re_ddate">               
                        </div>
                        <div>
                                <label for="title"><h4>Enter the books condition: </h4></label>
                                <select name ="re_condition" value="{{old('condition')}}">
                                    <option value="mint">Mint</option>
                                    <option value="good">Good</option>
                                    <option value="fair">Fair</option>
                                    <option value="poor">Poor</option>
                                </select>
                        </div>                       
                            <input type="submit" name="btn" value="returns">
                        </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

BookController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Book;
use App\Returns;
use App\Requests;
use App\Loan;
use Carbon\Carbon;


 class BookController extends Controller
{

    ......

    function returnform($loanid)
{

    $loan = Loan::find($loanid);
    return view('book/returnform',['loan' => $loan]);

}


function returns(Request $request, $loanid)
{

    $return = new Returns();
    $return->userid = auth()->user()->userid;
    $return->f_name = auth()->user()->f_name;
    $return->l_name = auth()->user()->l_name;
    $return->bookid = $request->re_bookid;
    $return->title=$request->re_title;
    $return->condition=$request->re_condition;
    $return->returndate= Carbon::now();
    $return->duedate=$request->re_ddate;
    $return->save();
    return redirect('profile');
}
```

routes

```
....

Route::get('returnform/{loanid}', 'BookController@returnform');

Route::post('returns', 'BookController@returns');
```

Comment: I wouldn't delete it, I'd set a `returned_on` timestamp and filter based on that.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a row in a table use the following code

```
function deletereturns(Request $request, $loanid) {
    $return = Return::find($loanid); 
    $return->delete(); 
    // return to some place
}
```

Add a route and its done.

But i suggest you to create a new column in the table with boolean and set default false. 
Each time a user tries to delete a loan just change false to true. 
When you list the loan use a where conditions  to exclude all the deleted ones.

This helps you to know who all deleted the loans, which may help in any way

Answer (score 0):

The `$loanid` parameter won't work in your method since you don't pass any value to it. You are however setting the loan id in a hidden form field. So do this to delete the loan using the loan id.

```
Loan::destroy($request->lid);
```

You should also add some check when a user returns the book. Check if the loan with the loan id exists and perform a check to see if the logged in user and the loaned user match. Because with your code right now, any user can return a book loaned by any other user.